# Regexp for validating .au domain names

Tags: php, regex, string

I need a quick regexp for validating that a string is a valid .au domain name. For example:

```
xxx.com.au
xxx.net.au
xxx.org.au
xxx.biz.au
xxx.--.au
```

all of these should be considered valid.

This should be pretty simple for someone not as hopeless with regexps as I am. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to only allow certain secondary TLDs in the .au space:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.(?:com|net|org|biz)\.au$/
```

Modify the list of secondaries separated by |'s as you desire.

If you don't mind about strictly validating the secondary TLD:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.\a+\.au$
```

And if you want to allow more subdomains (i.e. xxxx.yyyy.com.au):

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.\a+\.au$
```

You may need to use `a-zA-Z` instead of `\a` if the particular regex engine you're using doesn't support the latter.

Comment: This fails on the last one of his examples.

Comment: As stated in the answer, the list of secondaries should be edited to reflect whatever values are desired to be accepted.

Comment: Hi, can you please update this to not allow subdomains? I only want to allow primary domain  names since this is for a domain registration site

Comment: also I'm using PHP, do you know if that supports \a?

Comment: Updated for no subdomains (all that was necessary was to remove the period from within the brackets). I don't believe PHP supports \a, so I'll edit it to use a-zA-Z instead.

Comment: Also, you could simplify things and make it only a-z if you use the case-insensitive version of the regex match function (adding the "i" flag).

Answer (score 0):

```
^[\w\d-\.]+\.au$
```

That should work fine. You can't really do much else since what comes before the .au might add other second level domains on top of [the ones that already exist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.au#Second-level_domains).

Comment: Why \s? Last I checked domains didn't have whitespace in them.

Comment: Also, \w allows underscores, which aren't valid in domains. \d would be redundant if using \w since \w includes digits.

Comment: \s was a typo on my part which was only on the page for about 15 seconds. Surprised anybody caught it.

Comment: Freak timing I suppose. :) But you really do want \a instead of \w.

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Mine (Python's re module) doesn't allow \a.

Comment: Javascript's regex engine has it as a shortcut for alphabetic characters; if the engine you're using doesn't have it, you can use a-zA-Z instead, or if it's POSIX-compliant, [:alpha:]

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*)\.([com|net|org|biz])\.au
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.){2,}au$/i
```

For use with [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match) or other PCRE functions:

```
if(preg_match('/^(?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.){2,}au$/i', $domain))
    echo "'$domain' is a valid domain\n";
else
    echo "'$domain' is invalid\n";
```

Comment: What does the {2,} part do? I don't want any limits on the number of characters of the tld

Comment: `{2,}` means that (?:[a-z0-9\-]+\.) needs to appear *at least twice* before the 'au' at the end.